cordova build and submit testflight without xcode ide
I have a cordova app with the ios platform. I can open the xcodeworkspace, archive it and submit it to testflight. But I would like to do this via cli commands.
I've run:
cordova build ios --release -- --codeSignIdentity="iPhone Developer" --developmentTeam"my team id" --packageType="app-store" provisioningProfile="my guuid"

sucessfully. The teamId and the profile are the same as for Xcode, so I think they are correct.
In Xcode, I would click Product/archive. Then, in the Archives menu, I click "Distribute App" with the Distribution Method: "App Store Connect".
How can I do this via cli commands?

You can't publish to Apple via the command line. You have to use Xcode.
